# zsh : Testing the existence of a variable via indirect reference

Tags: zsh

If I want to know, whether variable v exists in zsh, I can use `${+v}`. Example:

```
u=xxx
v=
print ${+u} ${+v} ${+w}
```

outputs *1 1 0*.

If I want to access the content of a variable, where I have the NAME of it stored in variable v, I can do it with `${(P)v}`. Example:

```
a=xxx
b=a
print ${(P)b}
```

outputs *xxx*.

Now I would like to **combine** the two: Testing whether a variable exists, but the name of the variable is stored in another variable. How can I do this? Example:

```
r=XXX
p=r
q=s
```

Here is my approach which does NOT work:

```
print ${+${(P)p}}  # Expect 1, because $p is r and r exists.
print ${+${(P)q}}  # Expect 0, because $q is s and s does not exist
```

However, I get the error message *zsh: bad substitution*.

Is there a way I can achieve my goal without reverting to `eval`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print ${(P)+p}
print ${(P)+q}
```

The opening parenthesis of of a *Parameter Expansion Flag* needs to follow immediately after the opening brace. Also, it is not necessary to explicitly substitute `p` or `q` as `(P)` takes care of that. Nevertheless, `${(P)+${p}}` and `${(P)+${q}}` would also work.